# Forcing Ruby Time class to use ISO8601

Tags: ruby, time, iso8601

How do you force Ruby's `Time` class to use ISO8601 when `to_s` is invoked?

Comment: Wouldn't `require 'time'; Time.now.iso8601 #=> "2015-04-17T17:35:13-07:00"` be better than redefining [Time#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-to_s)?

Comment: This `Time#to_s` is called within a library that I have no control over.  This library will call `to_s` on any object I passed on to and save that to disk.  I want ISO8601 on the disk.

Comment: FYI, I have done this: `class Time; def to_s; iso8601; end; end`.  This seems to work but I am not sure if it's recommended to override `Time#to_s`

Comment: One option is to use [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), which were made permanent in v. 2.1: `require 'time'; module T; refine Time do; def to_s; iso8601; end; end; end` Then activate: `using T; Time.now.to_s #=> "2015-04-17T18:17:35-07:00"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DumpHole mentioned, you can always override Time.to_s like so:

```
require 'time'    

class Time
  def to_s
    iso8601
  end
end
```

But, you may not want to override `to_s` for all instances of Time. Instead you can create a custom wrapper class and use that:

```
require 'time'

class Iso8601Time < Time
  def to_s
    iso8601
  end
end

Iso8601Time.now.to_s #=> "2015-04-17T17:35:13-07:00"
```